# Draw lines between all the coordinates in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(5,1,3,2,5,7,12), y = c(5,7,6,1,3,5,6))
```

I can plot these coordinates with the ggplot function and draw a line between these coordinates:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(size = 3) + geom_line()
```

So far, no problems. But instead of a single line though the coordinates, I want that a line is drawn between all the coordinates. Creating a sort of spider web between all the coordinates. Is this possible in the `ggplot2` package?

Comment: "I want that a line is drawn between all the coordinates" does this mean that you want every single point to be connected to every other point?

Not sure if ggplot has it but some graph plotting package might be of a better use here

Comment: Yes, every single point has to be connected to every other point

Comment: try the `igraph` package and make a complete graph, then assign vertex coordinates based on your data frame

Comment: You said "spider web" suggesting you need to read up on [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph)s

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to do this in `ggplot2`, then you could use `geom_segment` for this. But before you can make such a plot, you have to create a dataframe which connencts each observation to the other observations. You could approach it as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  complete(nesting(x,y), id) %>%       # create the combinations
  select(id, xend=x, yend=y) %>%       # rename the new variables as end-points
  left_join(dat, ., by = 'id') %>%     # join with the original dataframe
  filter(!(x==xend & y==yend)) %>%     # remove the endpoints that are the same as the start points
  ggplot(., aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_label(aes(x = x, y = y, label = id, color = factor(id)), show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

which gives:

[image]

---

Used data:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(5,1,3,2,5,7,12), y = c(5,7,6,1,3,5,6))
dat$id <- 1:nrow(dat)
```

---

Alternatively, you can also add the row-id on the fly without doing it beforehand:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%        # add a row id
  complete(nesting(x,y), id) %>%       # create the combinations
  select(id, xend=x, yend=y) %>%       # rename the new variables as end-points
  left_join(dat %>% mutate(id = row_number()), .,
            by = 'id') %>%             # join with the original dataframe (also with an added row id)
  filter(!(x==xend & y==yend)) %>%     # remove the endpoints that are the same as the start points
  ggplot(., aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_label(aes(x = x, y = y, label = id, color = factor(id)), show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

Comment: even fancier :) I can't give out +1 again yanno :p

Comment: @MichaelChirico I'm having the same problem ;-)

Answer (score 14):

Using `base` plotting:

```
plot(data)
sapply(combn(nrow(data), 2L, simplify = FALSE), 
       function(x) do.call("segments", as.list(c(t(data[x, ])))))
```

[image]

Add bells and whistles to taste.

You may also use the `FUN` argument in `combn`:

```
plot(data)
combn(nrow(data), 2L, simplify = FALSE, FUN = function(cm){
  segments(x0 = data[cm[1L], 1L],
           y0 = data[cm[1L], 2L],
           x1 = data[cm[2L], 1L],
           y1 = data[cm[2L], 2L])
})
```

Comment: @MichaelChirico I took the liberty to add an 'all `combn`' alternative. Hope you don't mind. Just revert the edit if you find it redundant.